# SQL running the All Domain report out of ET by Job ID

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting

How do I create an SQL to run the All domain report when I have a list of Job IDs?

I am trying to use the Interactions > SQL within ExactTarget to run a query that will generate the whole All Domain report ( and either email or post the report to the FTP site). I want to generate it using the Job Id.

Comment: Do you mean SQL or SOQL?  Please give more detail about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to use the Interactions > SQL within ExactTarget to run a query that will generate the whole All Domain report ( and either email or post the report to the FTP site). I want to generate it using the Job Id.

Comment: What are you attempting to accomplish that is different than what the report currently achieves?  Do you have any SQL currently that you're using that is not giving you the desired results?  That report is pulling data from the Sent, Open, Click, Unsubscribe, and bounce tables so the query will most likely need to join all those tables and group the results accordingly.

Comment: Hello, Jeremy, I am trying NOT to use the interface to generate each report separately because the interface takes too long to select each individual job. Support has told me this is because there are "so many" jobs to display in one folder...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking a look at all of the System Data Views listed on the [Query Activity](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) wiki page.

Generally speaking, the canned reporting in SFMC/ExactTarget is based on these views.

I'd start with `_Job`, write your specific send jobs to a new `Job` data extension.  Then configure separate queries and data extensions, one for each of the activity views you want to include (`_sent`,`_open`, `_click`, etc.) and populate each one based on your new `Job` data extension.  Once you have data extensions for all of the views for a subset of send jobs, write another report query that aggregates data.

It sounds convoluted and it may sound easier to write one huge query, but don't do it.  You'll spend more time trying to figure out why it's not completing in the 30 minute timeout period.

Comment: I understand that the _Job could reference each job by ID, however, I don't understand the report query aggregating the data. Would this then break down by domain and be able to provide each line item for that domain (i.e. sent, unique open, unique click, etc.)? Are there any example online that show report query in action?

Comment: JobID is the key that relates the sends, opens, clicks and unsubscribe data.  You'll need to to use some joins and aggregate functions (e.g. count(*)) to summarize the data.